# TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' In vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, state, vuex

Facing an issue in the Vue project after upgrading the version of Vue2 to Vue3. In one of the scenarios, I'm upgrading the Vex state value with the existing value. As we know, after the state upgrade, the component will re-render. On the re-render, this error was throwing on the console, and the process got stopped.

Example scenario:

**Existing Value:**

```
let names = { nameOne: "Tobey", nameTwo: "Tom", nameThree: "Andrew" };
```

**New Value:**

```
let newNames = { nameFour: "Tony", nameTwo: "Tom", nameFive: "Chirs" };
```

**State update code:**

```
names = { ...newNames, ...names };
```

Vue version: **3.4.14**

Vuex version: **4.1.0**

**Error :** `TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' In vue3`

Can someone help me to figure out this issue?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. The error occurs in a renderer while there's no relevant code in question, that's all that can be said at this point